# Choosing between Modern Team site or Modern communication site for our HR site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, communication-site, modern-team-site, hub-site

We have a new sharepoint online tenant. and inside the built-in root site collection (which is of type classic team site), we added some document libraries and news web parts. Now we want to create our HR department site. and one of the questions i have, **if we should created this HR site as Modern Team site or as Modern communication site?**

I read this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites which mentioned that team sites are used for collaboration (group of users exchange info), while communication sites are used when a limited number of users publish content for other users. Our HR will be more aligned to be a communication site, since we will have the HR manager and 2 HR employees publishing some travel guidelines, holidays, general HR documents, etc... to all the users (which will have read-only permission on these content). and later on we might define this site as a hub site and have more detailed site collections for the HR functionalities.

But one issue for using the communication site, is that it does not allow to have the links on the left side of the site (as in the classic and modern team sites). And our end users mentioned that they need a consistent navigation experience, where since our root site collection have a left side navigation links,then they want to have the same for all the site collections.. So i am not sure if i should use the modern team site instead of the communication site just because we want the HR site to have the navigation links on the left side instead on top (as in the communication site case)?

Answer (score 1):

Since left navigation seems important to users, I would use the site with site template which includes left navigation and then control site behavior via permissions (and possibly site/site collection features).

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you advice more on what do you mean by `and then control site behavior via permissions` ??

Comment: @SharePointTestDev As per your clients' request (and take this advice with a grain of salt since I don't know the full request specification), few people from the HR dept would be members of default Owners/Members SharePoint groups depending on their scope of work and all other users would fall into Visitors group. If you need more fine-grained permissions, you can always set up your own custom groups. SharePoint groups are mapped to certain permissions. As for the features, I am guessing you'll be needing publishing features (site collection feature and site feature).